# Node.js read multipart/form-data POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, post

Im passing a file to node.js with AJAX. the file is passed as a Base64 string and I pass it using multipart/form-data. The AJAX part work flawlessly, but I need to have said string stored on a variable in server side i.e. in Node.js. Now, on PHP this would be super easy:

```
$someVar = $_POST["myBase64EncodedFile"];
```

How can I achieve exactly that but with Node.js? I have to use Node.js and I dont want the file to be saved in some temp folder, I just need the string on a variabe. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable) modules.

in express , you can ues it like this:

```js
var formidable = require('formidable');
const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
function handlerFormByEvent(req, res, next) {
  form
    .parse(req)
    .on('fileBegin', (name, file) => {
      console.time('start');
      console.log('name', name);
      file.path = `uploads/${file.name}`;
    })
    .on('progress', (accepted, total) => {
      console.log(`accept:%d,total：%d`, accepted, total);
    })
    .on('field', (name, field) => {
      console.log('field', name, field);
    })
    .on('file', (name, file) => {
      // handle file
      console.log('name', name);
      console.log(file.toJSON());
    })
    .on('aborted', error => {
      let message = error.message;
      res.render('error', { message, error });
    })
    .on('error', err => {
      console.error('Error', err);
      let message = err.message;
      res.status(err.status || 500);
      res.render('error', { message, error: err });
    })
    .on('end', () => {
      res.end('ok');
    });
}
```