# coverting to object or extract object

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I'm getting this:

```
--boundary
Content-Type: application/json; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Length: 35

{"SubscribeDevice":{"id":1}}--boundary
Content-Type: application/json; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Length: 643

{"Notification":{"CIDAlarm":{"CIDCode":"1602","CIDDescribe":"","CIDParam":"-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,NONE","CIDType":4,"UUID":"e588b915-f46b-468a-8644-cde5cae08bc4","ZoneNo":-1,"deviceNo":-1,"intercomTriggerEnable":false,"subSys":0,"timeZoneIdx":8,"triggerTime":"2022-11-29 14:19:02","uploadTime":"2022-11-29 14:19:02"},"activePostCount":1,"channelID":"0","channelName":"","dateTime":"2022-11-29T14:19:02-05:00","devIndex":"8AFAB0F0-2F31-47EE-86AA-67B648E4E8A3","deviceID":"alarm1","drvInst":"drv_ehome5_alarm","eventDescription":"CID Alarm","eventID":"548B3D73-03AB-4417-9954-226BFC29A128","eventState":"active","eventType":"CIDAlarm"}}
```

I just want get the object `Notification`, I'm doing this:

`eventData = JSON.parse(chunk.toString('utf8'));`

But I'm getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

How can I get only object Notification???

request part:

```
var options = {
    method: method, 
    body: body, 
    Headers:{
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
   },
}

const response = await client.fetch(URL, options).then(response => response.body)
.then( res => res.on('readable', () => {
    let chunk;
    
    while (null !== (chunk = res.read())) {
        console.log(chunk.toString()); 
}))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: are you asking how to extract the json string from the text? the json is invalid, btw

Comment: I'm getting that data of one endponit, It's possible extract object notofocation?

Comment: this object is invalid. you probably didn't paste the code correctly. please re-add the output of this statement: `console.log(chunk.toString('utf8'))`

Comment: I added ```console.log(chunk.toString('utf8'))``` and updated it

Comment: data  given wrong format

Comment: somehow you are getting the raw response with the headers. i would try to fix that problem instead of doing string cutting. if so, can you add code for the request part?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js read multipart/form-data POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56267052/node-js-read-multipart-form-data-post)

Comment: I don't sure but I added formidable and give me error